# Fetch .eml files with Dovecot

Tags: imap, dovecot

I have a local storage with number of .eml files. I would like to copy all such files to mailboxes located on the same server (CentOS box), so that users could view .eml content when fetching emails from the server. I am thinking of using Dovecot as IMAP server and Postfix as SMTP. I hope that my question is not too general, but is such configuration possible with Dovecot? Perhaps, I will need to convert .eml to some other format? I tried googling this topic but with no result. Maybe, there are far better approaches.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared there is a [script](http://www.broobles.com/eml2mbox/) which can convert `eml` files into `mbox` format. There is also another [script](http://batleth.sapienti-sat.org/projects/mb2md/) which can convert `mbox` to `maildir`. So, we can create a mailbox and convert `eml` files into it.